# Simple Product Filter Using Javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, search

I am creating a simple product filter using JQUERY. The result are showing for the check box values but not for Select Box Values. I would like to use both features. The results are showing according to the DIV class "xxx" value applied on each product. You can find a live example at:  [Demo]:   http://jsfiddle.net/shamsmaxcom/rc5ctjez/? "click here for live demo"  And the source code is pasted below. Please help. Thanks

```html
 <div id="solution_finder">
  <h1 style="font-size:27px; margin-top:45px; margin-left:40px; font-weight:normal;"> Product Filter </h1>
  <ul id="filters" style="list-style:none; margin-top:25px; line-height:30px; ">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="all" checked="checked" id="all" style="display:none;">
    </li>
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3xzoom" id="3xzoom">
      <label for="filter-category">3x video zoom</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="touch" id="touch">
      <label for="filter-category">Touch ID</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="burstmode" id="burstmode">
      <label for="filter-category">Burst mode</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="antireflective" id="antireflective">
      <label for="filter-category">Antireflective coating</label>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
  <div style="margin-left:43px;">
  <select id="genre" onChange="return selectOption();">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="with-retina">With Retina Display</option>
    <option value="without-retina">Without Retina Display</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div style="width:840px; height:148px; clear:both; margin-top:40px; margin-left:43px;">
  
    <div id="so_air2" class="category 3xzoom touch burstmode antireflective with-retina all" ><a href="#" ><h1>iPad Air 2</h1> </a></div>
    <div id="so_air" class="category 3xzoom with-retina all" ><a href="#" ><h1>iPad Air</h1></a></div>
    <div id="so_mini3" class="category 3xzoom touch with-retina all" ><a href="#" ><h1>iPad mini 3</h1></a></div>
    <div id="so_mini2" class="category 3xzoom with-retina all" ><a href="#" > <h1>iPad mini 2</h1> </a></div>
    <div id="so_mjni" class="category all" ><a href="#" > <h1>iPad mini</h1> </a></div>
          
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$('input').change (function() {
        var selector = $('input:checkbox').map(function(){ 
            return this.checked ? '.' + this.id : ''; 
        }).get().join('');
        var all = $('div[class^="category"]');
        if(selector.length)
          all.hide().filter(selector).show()
        else all.hide();
      });
 </script> 
</div>
```

Comment: You can split the listener (right now you've got an input change function) or you can check the selector.length, if empty (or how you want) you can check the value of the select.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your HTML and javascript code a bit to make it work.

This is the running [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rc5ctjez/4/).

The code that does the trick of using values of both checkboxes and dropdown is

```
$(':input').change(function(evt){

    var filter = $(':input:checked,select').map(function(index, el) {
        return "." + el.value;
    }).toArray().join("");

    $(".category").hide().filter(filter).show();

});
```

Mind that I've used `:input` selector instead of `input` to tell jQuery to also include `select` element when defining change event handler.

What change event handler does afterwards is

1. It generates a CSS selector filter:

   1. Selects all checked checkbox inputs and dropdowns
   2. Maps each resulting element to its CSS-class-compliant value (adding dot in front)
   3. Changes jQuery set to a normal array and
   4. Joins all strings together
2. Shows matching results by:

   1. Hides all result elements
   2. Filters them according to previously generated filter and
   3. Shows matching ones

**This filter uses AND predicate logic.** If you wanted to use OR, then the only difference would be when joining filter classes:

```
....join(", ");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked!. I added more select box with different features. It work seamlessly. Thanks again.

Comment: A better "Thank you" would be to accept my answer as the correct one - rewarding yourself 2 reputation points as well. :)